# quotes around path cause bat file to stop working

Tags: batch-file

I have a issue I don't understand...
I wrote a batch file to install some softwares, tried it and it works correctly.
I gave it to a colleague who tried it and it failed apparently because he had spaces in the path where he launched the file.
No problem ! Just gonna had some quotes and it will be alright I naively thought...
Alhough it worked perfectly without the quotes, I got an error message saying "Option non valide - "/quiet"." (invalid option - "/quiet") and got the same with "/S".
Here is the code:

```
echo Installation de Python 2.7.9
start /wait "%~dp0\python-2.7.9.msi"  /quiet /qn /norestart 
echo.

echo Installation de NSIS
start /wait "%~dp0\nsis-2.46-setup.exe" /S
echo.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
echo Installation de Python 2.7.9
start /wait "" "%~dp0\python-2.7.9.msi"  /quiet /qn /norestart
echo.

echo Installation de NSIS
start /wait "" "%~dp0\nsis-2.46-setup.exe" /S
echo.
```

When using `start` cmd takes the first thing in `"`'s as a window title. We fix this by assigning it a blank window title.

Comment: Works on my computer ! Thank you !